# Access Denied on X509Store.Open

Tags: c#, api, wcf

I am a total "newbie" when it comes to certificates and APIs so I am (naturally) stuck.
I have a WCF Service in which I create an HttpClient instance like this (for the methods to use to communicate with a third party API).

```
private HttpClient CreateClient(String ClientCertificate)
{
    string aAuth = Base64Encode(username + ":" + password);
    
    X509Store myX509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    myX509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    X509Certificate2 myCertificate = myX509Store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(cert => cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false) == *the name*);
    
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(myCertificate);

    HttpClient RetVal = new HttpClient(handler);
    RetVal.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + aAuth);
    return RetVal;
}
```

When I use the WCF Test Client to run a method, it works as expected.
If, however, I try to run it from another application, I get "Access Denied" when trying to open the store. (I decorated the API class with [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)] to get the line number in the API)

```
    the_API.theAPIClient g = new the_API.theAPIClient();
    the_API.int_APIReturnObject i = g.DoCaseStatus("some parameters");
```

Both applications reside on the same server.
Both applications were created using VS2017 (run as administrator). 
The certificate is in "Certificates - Current User->Personal->Certificates"
Since the exception from my "test harness" showed the line number of the error, I am presuming that the API and the harness are communicating successfully.
 Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
Roger

Comment: To call a WCF service, you need to create a WCF client, and the client and the service must have the same binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-client-overview

Comment: Hi Ding, they already do :(

Comment: You can try to open as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out (probably not the best solution but, it works)
I changed the API's Application Pool Identity to Administrator

Comment: Did you try to use "ReadOnly" when you opened the store? You're not modifying it.